# Laravel relacion uno a muchos con tabla pivot [reformulado]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

estoy haciendo una pagina donde los usuarios carga un formulario y después puede ir viendo los seguimientos, bueno eso es lo que intento hacer.
Trato que por medio de una tabla pivot `registro_user` relacione las tablas de `users` y `registros`.

**Modelos**

Este es el de user, que es por defecto el mismo de Laravel

```
public function registros()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\registro','App\Models\registro_user','registro_id','user_id','id','id');
}
```

Registros

```
class registro extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=[
        'nom',
        'ap_p',
        'ap_m',
        'rut',
        'nv',
        'mail',
        'logo',
        'dir',
        'ciu',
        'com',
        'fin'
    ];
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Pivot

```
class registro_user extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'registro_user';
    protected $fillable=[
        'user_id',
        'registro_id',
    ];
}
```

**Esta es la consulta que hago en el Controller**

```
class seguimientos extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('CheckLogin');
    }
    public function Index()
    {
        $_lista=User::find(Auth::user()->id)->registros;
        var_dump($_lista);
    }
}
```

El error que me da es el siguiente

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'registros.user_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `registros`.*, `registro_user`.`registro_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `registros` inner join `registro_user` on `registro_user`.`id` = `registros`.`user_id` where `registro_user`.`registro_id` = 1)
```

**Tuve que editarlo porque cambie la relaciones**

Comment: Bueno, no es que quiera obtener mas registros, necesito qeu me devuelva los datos de todos los registros de qeu cargo el usuario.
El cliente que busco tiene  id=1 y en vez de buscar todos los registros de la usuario me busca el id(en este caso 1) pero de registros

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener todos los registros que un usuario tiene asociados, considera proceder de la siguiente manera:

- Carga al modelo **`User`** y filtra solo aquellos usuarios que tienen al menos un registro vinculado con el método **`has`**
- Posterior carga todas sus relaciones mediante *eager loading* con el método **`with`**
- Para no traer la colección completa de usuarios y en cambio solo un objeto de usuario por su id usa el método **`findOrFail`**

  ```
  User::has('Registros')->with('Registros')->findOrFail($id);
  ```

Acotaciones:

- Revisa [la doc. De Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) para comprender el modo recomendado de declarar modelos para tablas intermedias
- La consulta propuesta te dará un objeto del usuario con al menos un registro asociado y una colección de registros
- Bajo este escenario solo necesitas iterar la colección de **`Registros`**
- Método [**`has`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) para verificar la existencia de una relación

Comment: Si la relación es *un usuario tiene muchos registros* entonces esta respuesta sigue siendo válida, lo único que se debe agregar en el código del OP es la declaración de ambas relaciones de Eloquent